# booststrap dropdown list in navbar not working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have navbar made by bootstrap, all navbar items appears after I run the project 
but the "dropdown list" item not work when I click on it
 I have this header:

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

And this the navbar code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx">MHM CAMM</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Convert<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Currency</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mass Measurements</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When I click Convert button the dropdown list not apears
My project uses asp.net and the IDE is VS2017
How to fix this please?

Comment: You import bootstrap before Jquery I think your error was there. Check snippet I edited your post to add snippet and noticed it was working for me

Comment: @Sam That's work, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your libraries is wrong. jQuery must be incuded before boostrap:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx">MHM CAMM</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Convert<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Currency</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mass Measurements</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```